# Dynamic Switch case Javascript with append value to different variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I want to do a switch with dynamic content in javascript, I will put an example i use 3 `cases`:

```
    for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {

        switch(hari) 
        {
            case 'senin':
                senin 
                += '<tr class="' + arr[i] + '">';
                senin 
                += '<td class="td'+hari + i + '">' + i + '</td>';
                senin 
                += '<td> <input type="time" class="form-control" name="waktu_1[]"> </td>';
                senin 
                += '<td> <input type="time" class="form-control" name="waktu_2[]"> </td>';
                senin 
                += '<td> <select class="form-control jenis_mapel" name="jenis_mapel[]" id="jenisMapel'+hari + i + '"><option value="pelajaran">pelajaran</option><option value="istirahat">istirahat</option><option value="upacara">upacara</option></select> </td>';
                senin 
                += '</tr>';
            break;
            case 'selasa':
                selasa 
                += '<tr class="' + arr[i] + '">';
                selasa 
                += '<td class="td'+hari + i + '">' + i + '</td>';
                selasa 
                += '<td> <input type="time" class="form-control" name="waktu_1[]"> </td>';
                selasa 
                += '<td> <input type="time" class="form-control" name="waktu_2[]"> </td>';
                selasa 
                += '<td> <select class="form-control jenis_mapel" name="jenis_mapel[]" id="jenisMapel'+hari + i + '"><option value="pelajaran">pelajaran</option><option value="istirahat">istirahat</option><option value="upacara">upacara</option></select> </td>';
                selasa 
                += '</tr>';
            break;
            case 'rabu':
                rabu 
                += '<tr class="' + arr[i] + '">';
                rabu 
                += '<td class="td'+hari + i + '">' + i + '</td>';
                rabu 
                += '<td> <input type="time" class="form-control" name="waktu_1[]"> </td>';
                rabu 
                += '<td> <input type="time" class="form-control" name="waktu_2[]"> </td>';
                rabu 
                += '<td> <select class="form-control jenis_mapel" name="jenis_mapel[]" id="jenisMapel'+hari + i + '"><option value="pelajaran">pelajaran</option><option value="istirahat">istirahat</option><option value="upacara">upacara</option></select> </td>';
                rabu 
                += '</tr>';
            break;
        }
    }
```

I am thinking put all cases to array like this : 
**['senin','selasa','rabu','kamis','jumat','sabtu']**

But I don't know how to put that in a switch in the most optimized way

Anyone have another solution to make it short ?

Comment: It looks like everything is identical in the cases other than the target variable, is that correct?

Comment: Does the value of `hari` change between iterations? How do the switch cases differ?

Comment: @FelixKling, `hari` is passed variable from parameter ...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, yes

Comment: So the value of `hari` is always the same across all iterations? But anyways, given your answer to T.J.'s question, there is no need for a switch statement at all, as long as you are OK with not using separate variables. Please post more of your code so that we get an idea of how those variables are defined and used.

Comment: @FelixKling, yeah it's always same ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible if you change your variable definitions. Whatever variables `senin`, `selasa` etc are, define them all as properties as an object instead of having many standalone variable names. Eg, instead of

```
var senin = 'some string';
var selasa = 'some other string';
// ...
```

do

```
var htmlsByCase = {
  senin: 'some string',
  selasa: 'some other string',
  // ...
};
```

Then you can just look up the property on the object instead of using `switch`. You can also use template literals to make it much more readable:

```
if (htmlsByCase[hari]) {
  htmlsByCase[hari] +=  `
    <tr class="${arr[i]}">
      <td class="td${hari}${i}">${i}</td>
      <td> <input type="time" class="form-control" name="waktu_1[]"> </td>
      <td> <input type="time" class="form-control" name="waktu_2[]"> </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control jenis_mapel" name="jenis_mapel[]" id="jenisMapel${hari}${i}">
          <option value="pelajaran">pelajaran</option><option value="istirahat">istirahat</option>
          <option value="upacara">upacara</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  `;
}
```

If the `hari` parameter is guaranteed to be one of those `['senin','selasa','rabu','kamis','jumat','sabtu']` which are now properties of the object, then there's no need for the `if` statement in the above code block.

Comment: I'd stayed away from template literals because I suspected an ES5-only environment, but I couldn't tell you why. (All the `var`s maybe.) Nice!

Answer (score 2):

You could give yourself a function to build the text, accepting parameters for the parts that vary:

```
function addContent(target, cls1, cls2, i) {
    target += '<tr class="' + cls1 + '">';
    target += '<td class="td'+cls2 + '">' + i + '</td>';
    target += '<td> <input type="time" class="form-control" name="waktu_1[]"> </td>';
    target += '<td> <input type="time" class="form-control" name="waktu_2[]"> </td>';
    target += '<td> <select class="form-control jenis_mapel" name="jenis_mapel[]" id="jenisMapel'+cls2 + '"><option value="pelajaran">pelajaran</option><option value="istirahat">istirahat</option><option value="upacara">upacara</option></select> </td>';
    target += '</tr>';
    return target;
}
```

*(No need for `+=` there, btw, see below...)*

Then:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
    switch(hari) {
        case 'senin':
            senin = addContent(senin, arr[i], hari + i, i);
            break;
        case 'selasa':
            selasa = addContent(selasa, arr[i], hari + i, i);
            break;
        case 'rabu':
            rabu = addContent(rabu, arr[i], hari + i, i);
            break;
    }
 }
```

If you find yourself using a `switch` to address discete variables like that often, though, consider putting the variables in an object as properties:

```
var theObject = {
    senin: ...,
    salasa: ...,
    rabu: ...
};
```

Then you can address them like this: `theObject[hari]`:

```
theObject[hari] = addContent(theObject[hari], arr[i], hari + i, i);
```

---

There's no need for a series of `+=` updating the same variable, you can just use `+`:

```
function addContent(target, cls1, cls2, i) {
    return target 
        + '<tr class="' + cls1 + '">'
        + '<td class="td'+cls2 + '">' + i + '</td>'
        + '<td> <input type="time" class="form-control" name="waktu_1[]"> </td>'
        + '<td> <input type="time" class="form-control" name="waktu_2[]"> </td>'
        + '<td> <select class="form-control jenis_mapel" name="jenis_mapel[]" id="jenisMapel'+cls2 + '"><option value="pelajaran">pelajaran</option><option value="istirahat">istirahat</option><option value="upacara">upacara</option></select> </td>'
        + '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: why the var cls return undefined https://postimg.cc/zLL5MyKP ?

Comment: @Aaron- That tells you that the variable you used in that case (`senin`, `salasa`, or `rabu`) had the value `undefined` to start with. Since you're *appending* to the value of the variable, if it starts out `undefined`, you'll get that text at the beginning. If you need to handle that possibility, add `target = target || "";` to the beginning of the function, before the `return` line.

Comment: @Aaron - BTW, I've fixed a couple of errors in the answer. You might want to hit refresh, or use CertainPerformance's answer if you can use template literals.